# Docker Tutorial Part 8 compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I'm doing this docker tutorial, but I keep encounter an error: [Image of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPboL.png).

and when i check my file:
[Image of Compose-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDIbe.png)

does anyone what i did wrong?

I am main follow the instructions on https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/

Comment: The various Docker tools run off of text files, not PNG images.  I'm guessing you have text files too; can you edit the question to include the `docker-compose.yml` file and the error message directly in the question as code-formatted text?

Comment: this looks like issue of tabs vs spaces to me, everything else lgtm, it's always a good practice to use a good IDE in these scenarios, where you can't tell the difference between tabs and spaces

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` should be on the level of `app`

**indentation matters here**..

you are adding `mysql` as sub comoponent of app service , but it should be on same level of `app` , as `mysql` is also one service